# C# Database Insert: The parameterized query expects the parameter, which was not supplied

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, azure, azure-media-services

I have a .net sdk application [see the git here](https://github.com/Azure/media-services-dotnet-deliver-drm-licenses). I'm trying to save some values from the sdk into my database, below is what i tried.

I created a mysql database table with the following columns:

```
"drm_key_id" VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
"drm_key" VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
"en_content_key " VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
"auth_policy_id " VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Im trying to insert values from the following objects:

```
key.Id, 
key.Id,
key.ProtectionKeyId, 
key.AuthorizationPolicyId)
```

Into my database using the following sql command:

```
new songadrmdataDataSetTableAdapters.songa_drm_keysTableAdapter().Insert(
                key.Id, 
                key.Id,
                key.ProtectionKeyId, 
                key.AuthorizationPolicyId);
```

But every time the program runs i get the following error:

> Additional information: The parameterized query '(@drm_key_id
>   varchar(48),@drm_key varchar(48),@en_content_key   v' expects the
>   parameter '@en_content_key', which was not supplied.

Comment: Insert operation require parameters to be defined...

Comment: Hey@user7417866 Could you show me a code example using my example above or would i have to re-write my whole query?

Comment: you need to rewrite your insert query, see my answer, I've provided links for better understanding on how to user parameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to query is not supplied, modify your insert operation to supply parameters..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx

https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

hope this helps :)